# vb.net function returns sqlcommand with using, how to use it

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to create a SqlCommand with using and return it to another function?

I want to call this function

```
Private Function ReturnSqlCommand(ByVal arg_context As CMAContext)
    Using objCmd As SqlClient.SqlCommand = arg_context.DbConnection.CreateCommand()
        objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        ' snip
    End Using
End Function
```

However as you can see this function does not return anything, my question is I do not think I can use using when I am returning the SqlCommand. I want to actually execute the command my caller function, such as

```
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = ReturnSqlCommand(context)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: Using disposes of the object at `End Using` so you cannot Use/Dispose of it **and** return it.  You should also turn on Option Strict

Comment: O/S is on Plutonix

Comment: `Option Strict On requires all Function, Property, and Operator declarations to have an 'As' clause.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wouldn't use the `Using` block where you *build* it in the function, just build and return the object:

```
Private Function ReturnSqlCommand(ByVal arg_context As CMAContext) As SqlCommand
    Dim objCmd As SqlClient.SqlCommand = arg_context.DbConnection.CreateCommand()
    objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    ' snip

    Return objCmd
End Function
```

Then you'd wrap it in a `Using` block where you *use* it:

```
Using cmd As SqlCommand = ReturnSqlCommand(context)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

The point being that the `Using` block should fully encapsulate the creation, use, and disposal of the object atomically.  Operations *within* that block (such as this function being called) are part of that overall operation.